# How to improve kyotocabinet Hash Database time effective

Tags: kyotocabinet

In the homepage of kyotocabinet, I see it cost 0.9 secods to  store data with hash database, but in my test , store one million data cost about 13 seconds. I find some Parameter can improve effective in http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/spex.html#tutorial, but after i tried it. it seems that has no effect.(data size is 120 Byte)
How can i improve the effective???

Comment: What parameters have you tried?